# How to improve the quality of the ListPlot output

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I need to plot massive data stored in external ASCII files. Below is the *Mathematica* code I use for this job:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

SetDirectory[" ... "];

dataRG = ReadList["dataRG.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
dataCH = ReadList["dataCH.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];

Vd = -((Md*(1 + δ))/
Sqrt[(1 + δ)*(b^2 + y^2) + 
x^2 + (a + Sqrt[h^2 + (1 + δ^2)*z^2])^2]);
Vn = -(Mn/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + cn^2]);
Vh = -(Mh/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + ch^2]);
V = Vd + Vn + Vh;

Md = 8200; b = 8; a = 3; h = 0.3; δ = 0.1;
Mn = 400; cn = 0.25;
Mh = 0; ch = 25;
E0 = -700;
z0 = 1;

f[x_, px_] := 1/2*px^2 + V /. {y -> 0, z -> z0};

xmax = 11;
pxmax = 41;
plrange = {{-xmax, xmax}, {-pxmax, pxmax}};

C0 = ContourPlot[Evaluate[f[x, px]], {x, -20, 20}, {px, -80, 80}, 
Contours -> {E0}, ContourStyle -> {Black, Thick}, AspectRatio -> 1,
ContourShading -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotRange -> plrange];

S1 = ListPlot[Flatten[List /@ dataRG[[All, {1, 2}]], 1], 
PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.8], PointSize[0.003]}];
S2 = ListPlot[Flatten[List /@ dataCH[[All, {1, 2}]], 1], 
PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.05], PointSize[0.003]}];
P0 = Show[{S1, S2, C0}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
FrameLabel -> {"x", OverDot["x"]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> plrange, ImageSize -> 550]
```

which produces the following output

[image: my plot]

As you may see from the image two are the main issues:

(1). How can I get rid off the vertical blank gaps?
(2). Why there are some "bold horizontal lines" in the plot and again how can I get rid off them?

I observed, that both issues are influenced by the `ImageSize` option. In particular, if you play with this option between 400 and 600, it might eliminate the problems. However, I suspect that the cause must be something more profound. So, I would be very grateful, if you suggest me how can I solve these issues and also if you could provide me with a more correct way to plot my data files.

Many many thanks in advance!

Both data files can be found here: [dataRG](http://www.mediafire.com/view/84y1m5qkrhn3h8n/daraRG.out) and [dataCH](http://www.mediafire.com/view/9e223p7wmg16m7w/dataCH.out).

Comment: Quite likely, those things you're seeing are moiré artifacts...

Comment: @0x4A4D They could be artifacts, but when I export the plot in different formats (.eps, .pdf, .jpg) they are still present messing up with my plot.

Comment: Though I didn't check your data, I agree with 0x4A4D it might be [moiré pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern). One way is to blur them a little when the distance between your adjacent points comes near the DPI of your monitor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data is on a *regular grid*, so it is also possible to put each data point into a matrix element, then use functions like `ArrayPlot`/`MatrixPlot` to efficiently plot it.

```
posCH = Reverse[{100, 73} + #/{1, 5}] & /@
                Union[Round[10 dataCH[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]];

posRG = Reverse[{100, 73} + #/{1, 5}] & /@
                Union[Round[10 dataRG[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]];

S12Array = SparseArray[{
                 posRG -> ConstantArray[.8, Length@posRG],
                 posCH -> ConstantArray[.05, Length@posCH]
                 }, {145, 200}, 1];

S12 = ArrayPlot[S12Array, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: S1 and S2]

In order to match `C0` (of which I changed the color to `Red` for highlighting) on it, we need to transform `C0`:

```
C0trans = C0 /. {
      GraphicsComplex[pts_, others__] :>
                     GraphicsComplex[{100, 73} + 10 #/{1, 5} & /@ pts, others],
      (PlotRange -> _) :>
                    (PlotRange -> ({100, 73} + 10 #/{1, 5} & /@
                                  (plrange\[Transpose])\[Transpose]))}
```

And we'll have to construct the `FrameTicks` manually:

```
xticks = Join[
   {100 + 10 #, #, {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[-20, 20, 2],
   {100 + 10 #, "", {.005, 0}} & /@ Range[-20, 20, 1/4]];
xticks2 = Join[
   {100 + 10 #, "", {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[-20, 20, 2],
   {100 + 10 #, "", {.005, 0}} & /@ Range[-20, 20, 1/4]];
yticks = Join[
   {73 + (10 #)/5, #, {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[-80, 80, 5],
   {73 + (10 #)/5, "", {.005, 0}} & /@ Range[-80, 80, 1]];
yticks2 = Join[
   {73 + (10 #)/5, "", {.01, 0}} & /@ Range[-80, 80, 5],
   {73 + (10 #)/5, "", {.005, 0}} & /@ Range[-80, 80, 1]];
```

Combine them:

```
Show[S12, C0trans,
 FrameTicks -> {{yticks, yticks2}, {xticks, xticks2}},
 FrameLabel -> {"x", OverDot["x"]}, RotateLabel -> False,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image: combined graph]

Comment: Also try the `ArrayPlot` with setting the `PixelConstrained -> True` option.

Comment: @shrx Thanks. This option does make the plot prettier. I didn't adopt it because OP explicitly specified `ImageSize -> 550`, which will contradict the `PixelConstrained -> True` or `PixelConstrained -> 1` option.

Answer (score 4):

You are forcing a regular pattern (your data) on a regular grid with a different spacing. This is bound to lead to aliasing. In your data vertical steps are 5 times larger than the horizontal steps:

```
Differences@(dataRG[[All, 1]] // Union) // Union
```

> {0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1}

```
Differences@(dataRG[[All, 2]] // Union) // Union
```

> {0.5, 1., 2.5}

The `AspectRatio->1` setting forces the data range ratio of ...

```
 ((Subtract @@ #2)/)Subtract @@ #1)) & @@ (P0 // PlotRange)
```

> 3.7272727273.72

to be 1, making the vertical step size a non-integer multiple of the horizontal one. That's trouble.

You will note that if you set `AspectRatio->Automatic` *and* the graphics size is sufficient the aliasing is gone.

Comment: If I set `AspectRatio->Automatic` the plot is too elongated at the vertical axes and therefore distorted! I want to believe that there is a much simpler solution which we haven't thought yet.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z As Sylvia already mentioned you could blur your data.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible way would be to use `Interpolation` (**Caution: Very slow!**):

```
posRG = Union[dataRG[[All, {1, 2}]]];

posCH = Union[dataCH[[All, {1, 2}]]];

posBoundary = Cases[C0, GraphicsComplex[pts_, __] :> pts, ∞][[1, 
   Most[Cases[C0, Line[pts__] :> pts, ∞][[1]]]]];

interpFunc = Interpolation[
                  Join[{#, .8} & /@ posRG,
                       {#, .05} & /@ posCH,
                       {#, .05} & /@ posBoundary]]

S12 = DensityPlot[interpFunc[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -40, 40},
            PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100,
            ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
            RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[f[x, px] < E0 /. px -> y]]]

P0 = Show[{S12, C0}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
          FrameLabel -> {"x", OverDot["x"]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
          FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
          AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> plrange, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could render it as a bitmap at a higher resolution, then scale it back down to size.  The image scaling algorithms will do a better job of representing the fine detail than ListPlot. This can be done easily with Rasterize.  For example, you can do

```
Rasterize[
 Show[{S1, S2, C0}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", OverDot["x"]}, RotateLabel -> False, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> plrange, ImageSize -> 550], 
 RasterSize -> 550*8]
```

[image: Rasterized version of plot]

Note that the resulting object is a bitmap, so won't look good if you try to resize it.